# Single resource URI to get access token to do SSO and use Files, Calendar API

Tags: single-sign-on, office365, office365-apps, azure-ad-graph-api, office365-restapi

We are building a Front End Application which uses Azure AD APP to do single sign-on with Office 365.

To get Access Token using OAuth authentication process, we need to pass resource URI which can be

1. xyz.sharepoint.com -- to integrate with SharePoint site collections
2. xyz-my.sharepoint.com -- to integrate with OneDrive for business
3. outlook.office.com -- to integrate with outlook graph.windows.net --
4. graph.windows.net  --  to use graph API for any search.

But to finish the single sign-on process, we need to fetch the user profile information at least email id is required. We were integrating with Onedrive for business in our Front End application.

So to get the user email, I can not get this information if I get the access token using resource xyz-my.sharepoint.com. I have to use xyz.sharepoint.com or graph.windows.net. So for our requirement, we have to fetch access token for 2 resources. It does not seem right, we had to maintain these access tokens along with refresh tokens to make these access tokens active.

Is there any other way to get an access token which can be used for all office 365 services OneDrive, Calendar, Mail, Outlook and Sharepoint?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the problem the Office 365 Unified API attempts to solve:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/office-365-unified-api-overview

Please take a look at the MSDN page above and let me know if you run into any issues integrating with the Unified API.

I hope this helps!
Shawn Tabrizi